# Access ORM object from controller files (Mikro-Orm)

Tags: javascript, express, orm, mikro-orm

What is the proper way to pass the orm object to my controller functions. I want to be able to access the orm instance I created so that I can perform CRUD operations.
My server file:

```
import { MikroORM } from '@mikro-orm/core';
import { __prod__ } from './constants';
import microConfig from './mikro-orm.config';
import express from 'express';

import expense from './routes/expense';

const main = async () => {
  const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);
  await orm.getMigrator().up();

  const app = express();

  // mount routes
  app.use('/api/v1/expense', expense);

  app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('server started on localhost:4000');
  });
};

console.log('==== STARTING ====');
main().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

My controller:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { Expense } from 'src/entities/Expense';

// Get all expenses for a user
// GET /api/v1/expenses/:id
// Private
export function getExpense(request: Request, res: Response) {
  res.send(`Get Expense: ${request.params.id}`);
}
```

Comment: Check how the express example apps work, they are quite bare bones, with a simple DI object that holds the reference. https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm-examples

Comment: Note that you _need_ to have dedicated request contexts. https://mikro-orm.io/docs/identity-map